# Interviewing for a tech position. The interviewer wants to ask about my "business skills." What should I be preparing?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, tech-industry

As the title says, I'm interviewing for a tech position and I've been told by the HR contact that the interviewer wants to ask me about my "business skills." My background is academia, and honestly I've never had a business-focused interview. I'm really not sure what they want to ask.

I'm being interviewed by my potential boss, and their role is a senior/managing Tech Person. The job would be consulting for an external client and I'd have some interactions with the clients. So I assume they want to know how I'd interact with the client. Or maybe how comfortable I'd feel in this kind of private industry job? I don't know what else "business skills" means in this context.

Comment: Don't assume. If you don't know what your contact meant by that phrase, ask them. We can't tell you; we don't have the context.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that "business skills" was that vague. This is helpful!

Comment: It can mean anything from skills dealing with customers to skills making presentations to the corporate board to skills in understanding financial tradeoffs to basic typing and accounting to ... basically, anything beyond "just build the thing" that makes doing so a sustainable business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Business Skills' is so broad, that this question may get closed.

Without knowing what industry or anything else that could narrow it down a bit, here is my best 'general' advice:

A business is concerned with making Profit. So when you are answering a question - think about these things:

1: Does it decrease the time taken to deliver to the client?
2: Does it decrease the cost taken to deliver to the client?
3: Does it increase the profit margin?
4: Does it create stickiness to encourage the client to continue doing business with you?
5: Does it add value for the client?

So, let's say you get asked the following Tech question:

"You are reviewing Products from Vendor X and Vendor Y for the client you manage - Both products are well respected in the industry and will meet the minimum requirements - what would you use to make your decision?"

In your answer, you want to make it with reference to one (or more) of those above points - for example:

"Vendor X uses a per-node licencing model, whereas Vendor Y uses a Per-Core licencing model. Since our setup generally involves a limited number of nodes, but each node having a large Core count, Vendor X would likely be the most cost effective solution for our clients needs"

Or

"We already have competencies in the business from other products from Vendor Y and being from the same vendor, there will be native integration, this should decrease the Total cost of Ownership and also reduce fault resolution time as we only have to deal with a single Vendor, thus leading to a better outcome for our Client"

Again, without details it's kinda hard to answer - but think of it this way - Academia tends to deal alot with idealized setups and hypothetical scenarios, whereas in the real world, everything is not always in spec, not to standards or properly maintained - and you need to make peace with that.

It might be that the technically correct way to solve a customer's issue is to spend tens or hundreds of thousands of dollars to do it 'properly', but there might be a solution that's 99.9% effective, that is a fraction of the cost.

Comment: Thanks. Even your first sentence is useful information.